# Unable to trim/trimend "$"

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I am trying to modify a PS script from online resource:

```
Trap {"Error: $_"; Break;}

$D = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
$Domain = [ADSI]"LDAP://$D"
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$Searcher.PageSize = 200
$Searcher.SearchScope = "subtree"

$Searcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=computer)"

$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName") > $Null
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lastLogon") > $Null

# Create hash table of users and their last logon dates.
$arrComp = @{}

# Enumerate all Domain Controllers.
ForEach ($DC In $D.DomainControllers)
{
$Server = $DC.Name
$Searcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$Server/" + $Domain.distinguishedName
$Results = $Searcher.FindAll()
ForEach ($Result In $Results)
{
    $DN = $Result.Properties.Item("samAccountName")
    $LL = $Result.Properties.Item("lastLogon")
    If ($LL.Count -eq 0)
    {
        $Last = [DateTime]0
    }
    Else
    {
        $Last = [DateTime]$LL.Item(0)
    }
    If ($Last -eq 0)
    {
        $LastLogon = $Last.AddYears(1600)
    }
    Else
    {
        $LastLogon = $Last.AddYears(1600).ToLocalTime()
    }
    If ($arrComp.ContainsKey("$DN"))
    {
        If ($LastLogon -gt $arrComp["$DN"])
        {
            $arrComp["$DN"] = $LastLogon
        }
    }
    Else
    {
        $arrComp.Add("$DN", $LastLogon)
    }
}
}
```

Script above give me the computername & its' last logon date, however the computernames are having "$" at the end. I would like to trim the "$" in order for me to use it remove the computer from AD later. However my script is not working.

```
$Compdollar = $arrComp.getEnumerator() | Select-Object Key | out-string

$AllComp = @()
Foreach ($inactD in $Compdollar) {
    $AllComp += $inactD.Trim("$")
    }

$Allcomp
```

The output is still computer name with "$", can anyone tells me why it wasn't trimmed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use double quotes with a $ as it is treated like a variable. Use single quotes instead.

```
$AllComp += $inactD.Trim('$')
```

Or use the backtick to escape the dollar sign.

```
$AllComp += $inactD.Trim("`$")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I tried both but the result still contains $. I tried
    $AllComp += $inactD.Trim("`$"," ") 
as well (suspecting there is space at the end) but the result is the same.

Comment: Another option would be this: `$inactD -replace '\$',''`

Comment: Hi Boeprox, that works! I got the desire result now. not sure why the trim not working though. Thanks anyway!